# Replacing float with flex

Tags: css, flexbox

How would I replace this float with flex?

https://jsfiddle.net/198muLhx/6/

```
.wrape .nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
}

.wrape .nav li a {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 4px 12px 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to class="nav"

```css
.wrape {
  position: relative;
  width: 266px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-position: 0 -168px;
  background-size: 100% 196.557%;
}

.wrape .nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrape .nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* float: left; */
  background: blue;
}

.wrape .nav li a {
  display: flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 4px 12px 0;
  color: transparent;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrape .nav li a:hover {
  border: 3px solid #5c91dd;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(n+11) a {
  margin: 0 4px 0 0;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(5n) a {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(8) a {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(1) a {
  border-top-left-radius: 25px;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(5) a {
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(7) a {
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  background: rgba(170, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(9) a {
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  background: rgba(29, 161, 242, 0.5);
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(10) a {
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  background: rgba(170, 255, 0, 0.5);
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(11) a {
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  background: rgba(255, 170, 0, 0.5);
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(12) a {
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 170, 0.5);
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(13) a {
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  background: rgba(44, 117, 255, 0.5);
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(14) a {
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  background: rgba(224, 17, 95, 0.5);
}

.wrape .nav li:nth-of-type(15) a {
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  background: rgba(243, 243, 21, 0.5);
}

.wrape .playButton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #e0115f;
}

.wrape .play,
.wrape .pause {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 6px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.wrape .pause {
  left: 0;
}

.wrapf {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 45px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 3px solid #0059dd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/K7OzsxI.png") no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapf svg {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.wrapf .lines::before,
.wrapf .lines::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 83px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #0059dd;
}

.wrapf .lines::after {
  left: 174px;
}

.wrapf .stack {
  position: relative;
  stroke-width: 6px;
  stroke: #89cff0;
}

.wrapf .play,
.wrapf .pause {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  fill: #f3f315;
}

.wrapf .pause {
  left: 10px;
}

a:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrape ">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="http://www.reuters.tv/" target="_blank" title="Reuters TV"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/NewsyHub/videos" target="_blank" title="Newsy"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/voxdotcom/videos" target="_blank" title="Vox"></a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" title="Google Documents"></a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" title="Radio Gadget"></a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank" title=""></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://hi5.1980s.fm/played.html" target="_blank" title="1980s.fm: Last Played"></a></li>
    <li><a> Audio Player</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://213.239.206.179:8488/played.html?sid=1" target="_blank" title="Blu Blu Lounge: Last Played "></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.radiobells.com/playlist/svoefm/" target="_blank" title="СВОЕFM: Last Played"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.radiobells.com/playlist/soundparkdeep/" target="_blank" title="SOUNDPARK DEEP: Last Played"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://s5.onweb.gr:8488/played.html" target="_blank" title="Cavo Paradiso: Last Played"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://onlineradiobox.com/us/retrohitmix/playlist/?cs=us.retrohitmix" target="_blank" title="Retro Hit Mix: Last Played"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.radiobells.com/playlist/rockfm90/" target="_blank" title="ROCK FM 90s: Last Played"></a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://46.105.118.14:15500/played.html" target="_blank" title="BeMy80s: Last Played"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="playButton" data-audio="http://jfm1.hostingradio.ru:14536/rock90.mp3">
    <svg class="play" width="38" height="40" viewbox="0 0 85 100">
      <title>Play</title>
      <path d="M81 44.6c5 3 5 7.8 0 10.8L9 98.7c-5 3-9 .7-9-5V6.3c0-5.7 4-8 9-5l72 43.3z" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="pause hide" width="36" height="40" viewbox="0 0 60 100">
      <title>Pause</title>
      <path d="M0 8c0-5 3-8 8-8s9 3 9 8v84c0 5-4 8-9 8s-8-3-8-8V8zm43 0c0-5 3-8 8-8s8 3 8 8v84c0 5-3 8-8 8s-8-3-8-8V8z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The better solution will be to add grid,

```
.wrape .nav{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
.wrape .nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  //float: left;
  background: blue;
}
```